# Classification of ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]$ to arbitrary unitary ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I’m working on the following question. Describe all of the ring homeomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to an arbitrary unitary ring $R$. As I understand this question could be answered with the following proposition

**Proposition 1:** Let $R$ be an arbitrary unitary ring, then $f\in \mathrm{Hom}\left(\mathbb{Z}[x],R\right)$ ($f$ is a ring homomorphism) $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\exists! r\in R \ \forall P(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x] (f(P(x)) = P(r))$.

This means that any homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}[x]\to R$ could be described by unique $r\in R$ such that $f$ maps any polynomial from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to its value at $x = r$.

*Proof:* The sketch of proof looks like this:

($\Leftarrow$) For the fixed $r$, the substitution of $r$ in $P(x)$ is obviously a ring homomorphism, as manipulations with polynomials preserve the unitary ring structure.

($\Rightarrow$) For a fixed $f:\mathbb{Z}[x] \to R$ let’s denote $f(x) = r$ (here $x$ is a polynomial $P(x) = x$). Now the proof is a straightforward calculation. $\square$

Somehow I still have some doubts about this reasoning. And also I wonder if the proof is the same for the generalized proposition

**Proposition 2:** Let $R$ be an arbitrary unitary ring, then $f\in \mathrm{Hom}\left(\mathbb{Z}[x_{1},x_{2},\dots,x_{n}],R\right)$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\exists! \vec{r}=(r_{1},r_{2},\dots,r_{n})\in R^{n} \ \forall P(x_{1},x_{2},\dots,x_{n})\in\mathbb{Z}[x_{1},x_{2},\dots, x_{n}] (f(P(x_{1},x_{2},\dots, x_{n})) = P(r_{1},r_{2},\dots, r_{n}))$.

Comment: Yes your proof is ok +  Yes it is the same for $x_1,\dots,x_n.$ But avoid your big formulas with a $\Leftrightarrow\exists!$ inside. Your translation in words is more useful and cleaner.

Comment: Yes, the proof is the same. $r_i=f(x_i)$ in the more general case. This is an example of a universal property. You could even have an infinite set $\{x_i\mid i\in I\},$ for any index set $I.$ Then any homomorphism $\mathbb Z[x_i]_{i\in I}\to R$ corresponds to maps $I\to R.$

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your recommendations @anne-bauval!

Comment: I thought about UMP also, while working this thing out. Thank you @thomas-andrews!

Comment: In a category theoretic sense, the function from sets to rings sending $I$ to $\mathbb Z[x_i]_{i\in I}$ is an adjoint function to the forgetful funct or from rings to sets.

Comment: @thomas-andrews Aha, I see!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's true if you're considering the category of *commutative* rings, But if $R$ is noncommutative then not every map $I\to R$ extends to a homomorphism $\mathbb Z[x_i]_{i\in I}\to R$: the elements in the image of $I\to R$ need to commute.

Comment: But probably the OP did mean to consider only commutative rings $R$, otherwise it's rather unnatural to apply a polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x_i]_{i\in I}$ to a sequence of elements of $R$.